# How transform a list of jsons into a dataframe?

Tags: python, json

I have a list of jsons looking like this:

```
[
{
'1': [{'code': '7654','location': 'California'}]
},
{
'2': [{'code': '7834','location': 'Texas'},{'code': '3912','location': 'NYC'}]
}
]
```

I would like to have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
id value
1  [{'code': '7654','location': 'California'}]
2  [{'code': '7834','location': 'Texas'},{'code': '3912','location': 'NYC'}]
```

I tried with json normalize but the problem is the keys numbers 1 and 2.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
import pandas as pd

values = [{
    '1': [{'code': '7654', 'location': 'California'}]
}, {
    '2': [{'code': '7834', 'location': 'Texas'}, {'code': '3912', 'location': 'NYC'}]
}]

pd.DataFrame(
    [{"id": k, "value": v} for value in values for k, v in value.items()]
)
```

---

```
  id                                              value
0  1       [{'code': '7654', 'location': 'California'}]
1  2  [{'code': '7834', 'location': 'Texas'}, {'code...
```